# Parametrizing curve with not only one peak

Tags: parametric

I obtained experimental data (thermal analysis) and need to parametrize the resulted curves for modeling. An example of two curves obtained:

[image]

[image]

I tried to use a Weibull distribution, but since I have two peaks, it seems that I need something bimodal. Requirements: a good fit, and be applicable to both curves above. What kind of equation is suggested for parametrization (I use Wolfram Mathematica)?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Since you face a multi-peak problem, you should use a linear combination of functions similar to the one you would select for one peak. The problem is that I am not sure that Weibull be a very good choice for the first problem.

This is a typical problem in spectroscopy (infrared, UV, Raman, ...).